# SQL partitions and use of analytical functions

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have been trying to create a table with 2 columns party_id and matched_party_id for identifying duplicates as explained below:

As you will see looking at the [First_NM+Last_NM+Zip_CD] we can identify few duplicate records. I want to match this and keep them within the umbrella of the most occurring party_id

```
PARTY_ID    FIRST_NM    LAST_NM ZIP_CD
----------------------------------------    
95678   JANE    DOE 7075
12345   JOHN    DOE 7000
10000   JOHN    DOE 7075
10000   JOHN    DOE 7075
95678   JOHN    DOE 7075
95678   JOHN    DOE 7075
95678   JOHN    DOE 7075
88648   JOHN    DOE 7075
88648   JOHN    DOE 7075
23456   JOHN    DOE 7075
95678   SAM DOE 7075
95678   SAM DOE 7075
```

Required Output

```
Party_ID    Matched_ID
-----------------------
95678   10000
95678   88648
95678   23456
```

since within a partition of duplicates we have identified 4 distinct party_id's
namely 95678,10000,88648 and 23456 and 95678 is occurring the most number of times so need to match all other party_id's with that party_id.

This is the code i am using. But failing for LEAD_PI null values

```
SELECT MAX_PI AS PARTY_ID, LEAD_PI AS MATCHED_ID from  
(SELECT DISTINCT B.FIRST_NM, B.MDDL_NM, B.LAST_NM, B.ZIP_CD,MAX_PI,LEAD_PI,  
FROM (SELECT I.PARTY_ID,I.FIRST_NM, I.MDDL_NM, I.LAST_NM,A.ZIP_CD,  
             LEAD(I.PARTY_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY I.FIRST_NM, I.MDDL_NM,   I.LAST_NM,  A.ZIP_CD ORDER BY I.FIRST_NM, I.MDDL_NM,I.LAST_NM, A.ZIP_CD) AS LEAD_PI,  MAX(I.PARTY_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY I.FIRST_NM, I.MDDL_NM, I.LAST_NM, A.ZIP_CD) AS MAX_PI  
      FROM INDVDL I JOIN PARTY_ADDR A  
      ON I.PARTY_ID = A.PARTY_ID  
     ) B  
WHERE MIN_PI <> MAX_PI  
AND MAX_PI <> nvl(LEAD_PI,0)
```

Comment: this is for oracle rdbms

Comment: What if two party_ids match, and both occur the same number of times? How do you choose the one to match others to?

Comment: in that scenario we can choose the max function and choose a party_id which is greater than the other.

Comment: we can relax the condition on the party_id (max or greatest etc.)column but the absolute requirement would be to have one party_id as the umbrella party_id which should not occur on the match_id side from the partition

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me whether all of the records in the input set are supposed to be duplicates, since they don't all have the same names (which was part of your stated method for finding duplicates), but they do all have a shared `party_id` at some point. Also, why is `12345` not in the result set?  `JOHN DOE` has that `party_id`, along with every other one.  Is that an oversight, or purposeful?

Comment: 12345 is not in the final result because it is not considered a duplicate. A duplicate is only when they have same first, last, middle name and zip code. I took a snippet from out production database and recreated few records here to illustrate my problem. i am looking for a query which goes through the entire table a] first identify party_id's for duplicate records, within this group there could be a possibility there are more than one party_ids which have duplicates. For such scenarios i need to classify them with one parent or umbrella id and all otherids as child or linked to this parentid

Comment: Oh, I see the zip is different, missed that initially

Answer (score 0):

It would be a bit simpler if your base table did not include any completely duplicate rows (and I'm not sure what the significance of such complete duplication could be), but you can do it with the data as described.  It looks like something along these lines would do what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT party_id, matched_id
FROM (
    SELECT
      MAX(i.party_id) OVER (
        PARTITION BY i.first_nm, i.middle_nm, i.last_nm, a.zip_cd
      ) AS party_id,
      i.party_id AS matched_id
    FROM
      indvdl i
      JOIN party_addr a  
        ON i.party_id = a.party_id
  )
WHERE party_id != matched_id
```

The inline view makes for a slightly simpler expression of that query, but I think you could do without.  You can also get the results you want without using a window function:

```
WITH nz AS (SELECT i.party_id, i.first_nm, i.last_nm, a.zip_cd
  FROM indvdl i JOIN party_addr a ON i.party_id = a.party_id)
SELECT DISTINCT
  ref.party_id AS party_id, 
  matched.party_id AS matched_id
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(party_id) AS party_id, first_nm, last_nm, zip_cd
    FROM nz
    GROUP BY first_nm, last_nm, zip_cd
    HAVING MAX(party_id) != MIN(party_id)
  ) ref
  JOIN nz matched
    ON ref.first_nm = matched.first_nm
      AND ref.last_nm = matched.last_nm
      AND ref.zip_cd = matched.zip_cd
WHERE ref.party_id != matched.party_id
```

Either way, I suspect that the `LEAD()` function doesn't do what you think, and I'm sure it doesn't do what you need for this job.